# How does process blocking apply to a multi-threaded process?

Tags: multithreading, process, scheduling

I've learned that a process has *running*, *ready*, *blocked*, and *suspended* states.  Threads also have these states except for suspended because it lives in the process's address space.

A process blocks most of the time when it is doing a blocking i/o or waiting for an event.

I can easily picture out a process getting blocked if its single-threaded or if it follows a one-to-many model, but how does it work if the process is multi-threaded?

For example:

I have a process with two threads in a system that follows a one-to-one model. *One handles the gui and the other handles the blocking i/o*. I know the process remains responsive because the other thread handles the i/o.

So is there by any chance the process gets blocked or should I just rule it out in this case?

I'm just getting into these stuff so forgive me If I haven't understand some of the important details yet.

Comment: This will be difficult to answer without a more specific context - there can be huge differences depending on the platform, operating system, system libraries, programming language and it's supported multi-{thread/process}ing model(s)...

Comment: I'm sorry if I can't get more into detail. There are still many things that I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a work queue where the UI thread schedules work to be done and the I\O thread looks there for work to do.  The work queue itself is data that is read and modified  from both threads, therefor you must synchronize access somehow or race conditions result.

The naive approach is to synchronize access to the queue using a lock (aka critical section).  If the I\O thread acquires the lock and then blocks, the UI thread will only remain responsive until it decides it needs to schedule work and tries to acquire the lock.  A better approach is to use a lock-free queue about which much has been written and you can easily search for more info.

But to answer your question, yes, it is still much easier than you might think to cause UI to stutter / hang even when using multiple threads.  There are various libraries that make it easier or harder to solve this problem, so depending on your OS and language of choice, there may be something better than just OS primitives.  Win32 (from what I remember) doesn't it make it very easy at all despite having all sorts of synchronization primitives.  Pthreads and Boost never seemed very straightforward to me either.  Apple's GCD makes it semantically much easier to express what you want (*in my opinion*), though there are still pitfalls one must be aware of (such as scheduling too many blocking operations on a single work queue to be done in parallel and causing the processor to thrash when they all wake up at the same time).

My advice is to just dive in and write lots of multithreaded code.  It can be tough to debug but you will learn a lot and eventually it becomes second nature.

Comment: I guess it's a matter of "minimizing the chances for it to happen" instead of "waiting for it to happen".  It really boils down to a good programming habit. I'm just curious, what happens to a process when a tug-of-war of resources between threads happen?

Comment: When two threads both try to acquire the same lock, one thread ends up blocking. Your goal really should be to write the code correctly so that resource contention doesn't happen. It may seem reasonable at first since contention happens rarely and resolves itself quickly, but software only gets bigger and more complex over time and you will find having an unsound foundation makes it very difficult to fix later.